# How to load function following new script-loaded row in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-sheets

I'm a noob trying to pull user details in a web app, display as a row in google sheet, and email the user.

I realize I can't run onEdit to run my working sendMail function if the edit was done via script, but I can't seem to get any alternative working.

I gather the simplest way would be to load my function from the function that populates the sheet, but I can't figure out how and I could really use help.

In my Code.gs file I have a function that handles transferring user data from my app to the sheet named 'handleResponse' and I have a function below which sends an email to the last contact listed on my sheet named 'sendEmailNow'. I've tried calling my sendMailNow function from within the handleResponse function with no luck and the 'onFormSubmit' trigger doesn't do anything as far as I can tell.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm losing hair.

The code I used can be found here: https://community.articulate.com/discussions/articulate-storyline/articulate-storyline-export-to-google-drive

I just don't know how to integrate a mail function with it.

Comment: Please show us the line of code that is trying to call the `sendMailNow()` function.

Comment: @SandyGood Presently no line of code is calling that function. It would seem the function is too long to add as a comment, but I copied all my code to pull in data to google sheets from this tutorial: https://community.articulate.com/discussions/articulate-storyline/articulate-storyline-export-to-google-drive

You'll see the code in step 7, it's named 'handleResponse' thanks so much for any insights!

Comment: You need to learn some basic JavaScript.  You need to make a commitment of time and effort to learn some basic JavaScript concepts.  Search "javascript tutorial"

Comment: It would be super helpful if someone could show me where to call my mail function within the code.

Comment: If I can't get this sorted I'll run my function on a daily trigger which is not ideal as people are accustomed to getting form results sent to them right away. I am not a javascript dev. I work with Storyline and have struggled for weeks to get this all working to this level. I would gather someone who understands javascript my question would be pretty straight forward and as a motion designer I'm used to helping noobs with their one problem without suggesting they go take a course in after effects.

Comment: You can call a function by using the function name with parenthesis on the end.  `myFunctionName();`  Just put it at the very end, before the `} catch() {`

Comment: Thanks Sandy, this is actually the first thing I tried and it doesn't run the function. If I run my sendEmail function directing from the script editor it sends the email as expected. Does it matter the order of my functions? Presently My mail function is below the handleResponse function calling it. Also, is scope an issue? Sorry my coding knowledge ended with actionscript2 so my questions might be dated. Wish I could get this sorted. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If your `sendEmail()` function is inside of the `handleResponse` function, then the order can make a difference.  If the `sendEmail()` function is inside of the `handleResponse` function, then the `sendEmail()` function should be put at the top.  If the `sendEmail()` function is not inside of any other function, then the order does not matter.

Comment: Ok well this is a separate function so it's not that. Thanks for the help. I need to get this running by Friday and still have lots of other stuff to take care of so I'm gonna have to dump this and use a time trigger. I just don't get why it isn't running the function... I need to learn more about logs and consoles. :(